# Array ordering logic

Tags: swift, data-structures

I have a swift array having 5 elements in some order.[A1, B2, C3, D4, E5]
I have another empty array. 5 options which are present in the first array may be input to be inserted.

While the values gets inserted, it needs to in a order as of base array.
Let us say first D4 gets inserted, so D4 will be inserted in array [D4]

If A1 gets inserted, then array order will be [A1, D4]
If E5 gets inserted, then array order will be [A1, D4, E5]

Any one kindly suggest some logic for the same.

Comment: What is your tried code. It looks like a simple sorting and thousands of answers are posted

Comment: I strongly suspect that arrays of strings is the wrong model for what you are trying to do. If you have a finite set of options, use an enum!

Comment: Also, why do the values get inserted in an order different from the reference array? Please share some of the context so the actual problem you're trying to solve becomes clear.

Comment: Test case: We have a combo box with options. Once we select a option then it gets removed. When user tries to revert back that option should go into its correct ordering with whatever options are left.  It is not a case of normal sorting, the option has a base order of its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect sorting order which can be implemented as follows:

```
let base   = ["A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5"]
let order  = [String:Int](uniqueKeysWithValues: base.enumerated().map{($1,$0)})

var selection:[String] = []

func addToSelection(_ value:String)
{ selection = (selection + [value]).sorted{order[$0]! < order[$1]!} }

// adding values ...
addToSelection("D4")   // ["D4"]
addToSelection("E5")   // ["D4","E5"]
addToSelection("A1")   // ["A1","D4","E5"]
```

.

If you're using Swift 3 (or if you prefer that notation) the order dictionary could be initialized like this:

```
let order:[String:Int] = ["A1":1, "B2":2, "C3":3, "D4":4, "E5":5]
```

.

.

Another way that does not involve a sort would be to use your selection as a filter on the base array:

```
let base ["A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5"]

var selection:[String] = []

func addToSelection(_ value:String)
{ selection = base.filter{selection.contains($0) || $0 == value } }
```

But this actually returns elements of the base array (not of the selection) which may be an issue if you're working with objects rather than mere strings.

Comment: Thanks Alain, it worked perfectly.. Yes we are only using String.